# How to theme customer/account/logoutSuccess page

Tags: magento2, redirect

In Magento 2, when a user logs out of their account, they are redirected to **`customer/account/logoutsuccess`** page, which then redirects to the homepage after 5 seconds.

How can I temporarily disable this redirect so that I can theme it with custom CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy this file in your theme

**From**

> vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/logout.phtml

**To**

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Customer/templates/logout.phtml

Now just comment this line

```
// $($.mage.redirect("<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getUrl() ?>", "assign", 5000));
```

Answer (score 0):

**By Default page will redirect after 5 second,
5 second setting are coming from logout.phtml file.**

Just change value at below line

```
$($.mage.redirect("<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getUrl() ?>", "assign", 5000));
```

To,

```
$($.mage.redirect("<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getUrl() ?>", "assign", 36000));
```

Now page will redirect after 10 Hour.
**You can change value according your need and after your work is completed you can set 5000 in above file.**

Core file is,

```
vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/logout.phtml
```

Comment: Hi https://magento.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/96764  please give clarity bro, why did you reject?